# Sql Server: Determining which transaction logs need to be restored

Tags: sql-server, backup-restoration

If you have (say) 10 transaction log backups and some, all or none may have been restored to the database. Is there a way to determine which files have already been restored?
Thanks
Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to match up the first/last lsn from running `RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK = N'E:\PathToBackup\test.trn' WITH NOUNLOAD`

With the LSN info from `dbcc log (mydb)`

The LSN from the dbcc command needs to be converted to be usable however. For example, if you have an LSN from the dbcc log command that looks like `00000014:00000157:0003` you would need to do the following:

```
select
left(convert(int, 0x00000014) * 1000000, 6) +
right(convert(int, 0x00000157) + 1000000, 6) +
right(convert(int, 0x0003) + 1000000, 5)
```

Note: There is a little bit of debate [out there](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic463635-357-1.aspx) about how to convert this properly, and the solution above is a bit of a hack.  The best way is with the UDF in [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/886839).

Comment: Fantastic! This looks like exactly what I need